# Upgrading Rails app from 3.2.6 to 3.2.18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, upgrade

I have a Rails app that was built on 3.2.6. I want to upgrade it to the latest version of 3.2 (which seems to be 3.2.18). Can anyone tell me what changes will need to be made besides just changing the Rails version number in the Gemfile? Is there a more stable version I should be upgrading to instead of 3.2.18? I am extremely new to Rails development and I am not finding much help elsewhere on the web.

EDIT: I tried updating to 3.2.18 briefly just to see if the behavior of my application changed, and once I had done so, the main page would not even load, claiming the template was missing. This seems to indicate that I need to manually go in and fix something.

Comment: Why do you need to move from 3.2.6 to 3.2.18 if you are not sure of what the differences are?

Comment: I know there are security fixes in the more recent versions, which I definitely want - I'm just not sure of other differences that I might need to make myself in my code.

Comment: Nothing about the use of a layout changed between 3.2.6 and 3.2.18.  It sounds like there might be another issue.  Can you update your question with your development log output after upgrading?

Answer (score 2):

Rails uses semantic versioning.  This means that 3.2.x will work if the application was working in any version of 3.2.x.

The latest stable version of Rails is 4.1.  I would recommend building new applications with the latest version, unless you know for certain a required feature was deprecated.

EDIT:  This response on rails core describes the versioning https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9979

```
X.Y.Z

Z - only bug fixes, no API changes.
Y - new features, may contains API changes.
X - new features, will contains API changes. Just bumped in special occasions
```

Comment: Rails uses the ["Rails adoption"](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9979) of the semantic versioning schema. While (in most cases) it's true, that any TEENY versions are compatible with each other, I would not expect a painless upgrade when the MINOR changes... ;-)

Comment: I tried updating to 3.2.18 briefly just to see if the behavior of my application changed, and once I had done so, the main page would not even load, claiming the template was missing. This seems to indicate that I need to manually go in and fix something.

Answer (score 0):

change the rails version in Gemfile and run 'bundle update rails'